# TypeScript 2 'Cannot find a name Promise' error in IDEs

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I already tried target es6, but it gave me many compilation errors. Without target es6 everything is fine, but IDE (studio code, webstorm) keep telling me that cannot find name Promise. And that's because of TypeScript checks in editors.

Someone had this error? Pretty annoying, actually. Always having red Promise.

TypeScript 2.0.3, WebStorm also checking with 2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the relevant parts of the [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts) that you need.

The definition for [Promise there](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L5221) is:

```
interface Promise<T> {
    then(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null): Promise<T>;
    then<TResult>(onfulfilled: ((value: T) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null, onrejected: (reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>): Promise<T | TResult>;
    then<TResult>(onfulfilled: (value: T) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): Promise<TResult>;
    then<TResult1, TResult2>(onfulfilled: (value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;
    catch(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null): Promise<T>;
    catch<TResult>(onrejected: (reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>): Promise<T | TResult>;
}
```

And the one for [PromiseLike](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L1319):

```
interface PromiseLike<T> {
    then(
        onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null,
        onrejected?: ((reason: any) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null): PromiseLike<T>;
    then<TResult>(
        onfulfilled: ((value: T) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null,
        onrejected: (reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>): PromiseLike<T | TResult>;
    then<TResult>(
        onfulfilled: (value: T) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>,
        onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): PromiseLike<TResult>;
    then<TResult1, TResult2>(
        onfulfilled: (value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>,
        onrejected: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>): PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2>;
}
```

Take that and put it in your own `.d.ts` file and use that.
If you need more parts just take them from the `lib.es6.d.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add all needed declarations in your `tsconfig.json`. In your case it

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "lib": ["es6","dom"]
  }
}
```

By default ts uses es5 definitions that include PromiseLike but not Promise

Answer (score 0):

Solution is: add you file into tsconfig.json "files":

```
{
  "files": [
    "./src/your-file.ts",
    "./typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

When your file is not added into tsconfig, IDE can't provide types to it.

Answer (score 0):

for me I just did

```
import { promise } from 'protractor'
```

and everything is fine